# Magent 2.3.4 Installation error

Tags: magento2, php, composer, fatal-error, setup

**I was do setup the magento 2.3.4 version in Php 7.3 version**
**But Frontend throw error**

> Fatal error: Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 7.4.0". You are running 7.3.33-1+ubuntu20.04.1+deb.sury.org+1. in /magentoroot/vendor/composer/platform_check.php on line 24

**After i runed below commands :

composer install, composer update and composer -v

it is thow error**

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Composer\Json\json_decode() in /usr/share/php/Composer/Json/JsonFile.php:169

**How to solve this problem ?**

Comment: Try `composer clear-cache` and try again. If this doesn't help, uninstall composer and reinstall it.

Answer (score 0):

Update Project or global composer.json file under config section :

```
{
    "config": {

        "platform-check": false
    }
}
```

After that Run commands :

```
composer update
composer dump
```

After that Run the magento commands for *setup upgrade, compile and deploy* commands.

Hopefully It will resolve.